# How to use bitwise operations to assign specific bits of a byte according to two other bytes? (bit blend according to a mask)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have 3 bytes.

- One byte determines which bits of the 3rd byte need to change (1 indicates bit needs to change 0 means no change should occur).
- The 2nd byte determines whether the changing bits are assigned 1 or 0.
- The 3rd byte is where changes take place.

Is there a way I can achieve this using bitwise operators? If so, how?  A simple formula or program to achieve this would be nice (preferably in c).

Example:

```
BitsToAssign:   0b01101011
ValuesToAssign: 0b01000010
ByteToAlter:    0b11110001

ExpectedResult: 0b11010010
```

Comment: I tried reading this three times. I have no idea what you are asking, other than "can i achieve this with bit wise operations" the answer is yes. https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators

Comment: almost duplicate:  [Merge bit sequences a and b according to a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282691).  And [Swapping bits at a given point between two bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3562347) goes farther, producing two outputs with certain bit-positions swapped.  (A masked xor bit-difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard bithack for this is "[Merge bits from two values according to a mask](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#MaskedMerge)" - I added your variable names for the inputs to the existing comments from Sean Anderson's collection of bithacks.

```
unsigned int a;    // (ByteToAlter)    value to merge in non-masked bits
unsigned int b;    // (ValuesToAssign) value to merge in masked bits
unsigned int mask; // (BitsToAssign)   1 where bits from b should be selected; 0 where from a.

unsigned int r;    // result of (a & ~mask) | (b & mask) goes here

r = a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask);
```

As the bithack comments note, the straight-forward way is `(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)` - clear the bits you're not keeping in each input, then OR them together.

#### How `a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask)` works:

`bitdiff = a^b` is the bitwise difference between those inputs.
It has a `1` where they differ, and a `0` where they're the same.  (By definition of XOR).

`a ^ bitdiff` would flip every bit in `a` that's different from `b`.  In fact, `b == a ^ bitdiff`.
One way to show that's true is that XOR is associative, so  `a ^ (a^b)` = `(a ^ a) ^ b`.
And `x^x` = 0, just like `x-x = 0`.
`0 ^ x = x`, so `(a^a) ^ b` = `0 ^ b` = `b`.

But if we mask the bitdiff to only set bits of `a` to bits from `b` at certain positions, we've achieved our goal: bitwise blend according to a mask.  `blend = a ^ (bitdiff & mask);`

---

#### Special cases of the `(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)` simple version

If your inputs are arranged so `ValuesToAssign` only has any `1` bits at positions selected by the mask, you can optimize away the `b & mask` part, leaving just `(a & ~mask) | b`.  ([Eraklon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68048922/how-to-use-bitwise-operations-to-assign-specific-bits-of-a-byte-according-to-two/68049185#68049185)). Clear the unselected bits, then OR in the new values to set any bits that should be set.

A further special case is when `ValuesToAssign == BitsToAssign`, i.e. the modification only ever sets bits, never clearing them.  That's what OR does, so of course this case optimizes to `a | b`, with no need to clear bits in `a` before ORing.

---

#### Efficiency:

`r = a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask);` is only 3 boolean operations,
vs. 4 for `(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)` if all three inputs are runtime-variables.  (One bitwise NOT, two AND, plus an OR).

If `mask` is a constant, then constant-propagation into `~mask` makes it a constant, and most machines can do AND-immediate with at least an 8-bit AND mask.  So you'd still only need 3 instruction: two ANDs (with inverse constants) and an OR.

Some machines (like x86 with BMI1) even have an [`andn`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/andn) instruction that does `x & ~y`, allowing the `(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)` to be done with 3 instructions.

For latency, `(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)` has more **instruction-level parallelism**.  If `mask` and `~mask` are ready ahead of `a` and `b`, there are only two parallel AND operations, and an OR, from `a` and `b` inputs being ready to the output being ready.  On a normal superscalar machine (that can do two independent AND ops in the same cycle), that's only 2 cycle latency from inputs to outputs.  (Again, assuming `mask` is ready early, or that an instruction like `andn` exists to do `a & ~mask` in a single operation).

If the critical path goes through `mask` (i.e. it's not ready early), and you don't have an instruction like `andn` to do `~` and `&` as one operation, the latency from `mask` to `result` is 3 operations, `~`, `&`, and `|`.  (Assuming the `b & mask` can run in parallel without slowing down any of those three).

**Latencies for `(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)` on a modern OoO exec machine.**
([Not the same thing as throughput cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692718/how-many-cpu-cycles-are-needed-for-each-assembly-instruction/44980899#44980899))

- a -> result: 2 cycles
- b -> result: 2 cycles
- mask -> result: 3 cycles (or 2 on some machines)

**But the bit-difference way doesn't have any ILP**; it's a chain of 3 operations.  `a^b` requires both of those inputs to be ready for the first step, then `mask` needs to be ready for the `& mask` step.  The final `a ^ ...` step is using inputs that were already needed earlier.  So it's only 3 operations, but they're serial.

**Latencies for `a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask)` on a modern OoO exec machine.**

- a -> result: 3 cycles
- b -> result: 3 cycles
- mask -> result: 2 cycles

Related Q&As:

- [Merge bit sequences a and b according to a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282691) - this is called a blend in SIMD programming.  IDK if anyone else uses the "bit-blend" term I like to use for this operation, but IMO that clearly describes it.  x86's AVX-512 extension has a 3-input boolean operation `vpternlog` with a truth-table from an 8-bit immediate, and thus can do it in a single instruction.
- [Swapping bits at a given point between two bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562347/swapping-bits-at-a-given-point-between-two-bytes/50839334#50839334) - The same bithack idea, but applying the masked bit-difference to *both* inputs to exchange bits at the mask positions.
- https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks - starts gently with an intro to the operators (like `^` being bitwise XOR).  Includes bithacks that use + and - (and the carry propagation effects of hitting a 1 or 0, like `x & (x-1)` to clear the right-most set bit.)
- https://agner.org/optimize/ for more about tuning for modern CPUs.

Comment: Actually modern compilers will generate the same code for both. No difference at all. That is the reason I always say that compilers are usually  far better in micro-optimizations than humans https://godbolt.org/z/9ovvxrhvv

Comment: @0___________ thanks, usually I do check compiler output.  (Especially since 2-operand ISAs like x86 may need extra `mov` instructions.)  Interesting that GCC knows this optimization.  Clang also knows it (https://godbolt.org/z/x57vKzfds), and with `-march=haswell` will use BMI1 `andn` to compile both versions to `andn` / `and` / `or` (with no MOV needed).  But without BMI1, it chooses to compile both as written.  (Requiring one MOV in each).

Comment: @0___________: Unfortunately GCC `-O3 -march=haswell` applies this peephole even though andn/and/or would be more efficient :/  https://godbolt.org/z/hKrsTfGaT

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation:) it is really helpful even though I don't completely understand all of the parts.

Comment: @Mr.0099: If want to see it in action to understand better, try it yourself with a 4-bit example.  (Or a simple example in the low 4 bits or separate hex digits of a `char` so you can single-step it in a debugger.  Especially if you assign each intermediate result to a separate C variable, if you want to do source-level debugging instead of looking at the asm which necessarily has to use separate machine instructions.)  Or if you meant not understanding all the microarchitectural details, or latency / dependency chains, that's optional and can take some time to wrap your head around.

Answer (score 2):

`BitsToAssign & ValuesToAssign | ~BitsToAssign & ByteToAlter`
Please try this.

Explanation: Select `ValueToAssign` if `BitsToAssign` is True else select `ByteToAlter`

Comment: You want `~`, bitwise NOT, rather than `!` logical NOT.

Comment: Also, that's more operations than `a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask);`.  [Merge bit sequences a and b according to a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282691)  For latency, this way has more instruction-level parallelism, though, and doesn't require bittoalter and valuestoassign to both be ready before making any progress.  Although if your BitsToAssign is a constant, masking with it directly and inverted can optimize away the `~`, and for single bytes most ISAs can do an AND-immediate with an 8-bit mask.

Comment: Your explanation part and using keywords for operators really helped me understand how your formula gets to my desired result. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
void printbin(unsigned char val)
{
    unsigned char mask = 1 << (sizeof(mask) * 8 - 1);
    while(mask)
    {
        printf("%c", val & mask ? '1' : '0');
        mask >>= 1;
    }
}

unsigned merge(unsigned ByteToAlter, unsigned ValuesToAssign, unsigned BitsToAssign)
{
    unsigned clearMask = ~BitsToAssign;

    return (ByteToAlter & clearMask) | (ValuesToAssign & BitsToAssign);
}

int main(void)
{
    printbin(merge(0b11110001, 0b01000010, 0b01101011));
    
}
```